# File is shown as deleted while merging branch to trunk

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

i am merging branch to trunk using tortoise svn option `Merging Two Different Trees`

I have file i.e file1 under trunk but not on branch

I have checked  out trunk to my local .then  did
`Right- click > Merge > Merging Two Different Trees >  mentioned from as trunk url and to as branch url > Test merge`

Now file1 is shown as deleted under  `Test merge results` **but why ?** Ideally it should ask me that this file does not exist under branch but
exist on trunk. Do you want to keep it or not ? **Is there an option of doing it ?**

**UPDATE :-**

on 1st june i created the branch from trunk. on 5th june i added the file1 under trunk. Now when when i am trying to merge branch to trunk, should it
be displayed as deleted ?

Comment: This is not really a Java specific question...

Comment: `Merging Two Different Trees` is TOTALLY WRONG choice for reintegration branch. Start from `svn help merge` + SVN Book and read carefully

Comment: But this is what suggested at http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html. See "If you are using this method to merge a feature branch back to trunk, you need to start the merge wizard from within a working copy of trunk."  under section "Merging Two Different Trees"

Comment: "If you are using" do not means, that this method *should be* used for reintegration. "This is a more general case of the reintegrate method", but you obviously need less general - `Merge a range of revisions` :) Also read http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html (especially sections Keeping a Branch in Sync and Reintegrating a Branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the branch from trunk and then deleted the file in the branch it is counted as change after the branching date. So like the other changes that you want to merge you merge this one too (deleting the file).

If the file is deleted in separate commit you can merge without this revision (you specify which revisions to merge in turtoise).

Also you merge locally and then you commit the merged version. So the deleted file is deleted only in your local computer. When you commit the merge to the repository you can uncheck the deleting of the file or revert the deleting of the file. This way the trunk will still have the file.

Comment: on 1st june i created the branch from trunk. on 5th june i added the file1 under trunk. Now when when i am trying to merge branch to trunk, should it
be displayed as deleted ?

Comment: Well this is a conflict since you modify the version in two branches so you should resolve it during the merge. The SVN sees the difference but doesn't know which one is correct. Maybe it should give a tree conflict for this file instead of showing it as deleted. 

You can merge the revision where you added that file from the trunk to the branch and then merge the branch to the trunk. Or you can merge the trunk and commit the merged version unchecking deleting the file.

Comment: you said "Well this is a conflict since you modify the version in two branches " but I just added it under trunk after branch is created.  I did not modify in under two branches. Is this the right behavior of SVN(where if I add files in trunk after branch has been cut, then file will be shown as deleted if I merge branch back to trunk)

Comment: I understand that I can uncheck the deleting of the file or revert the deleting of the file but I want to understand the svn behavior here

Comment: Trunk is also a branch. Your project divides in two versions on 1st of June - Trunk (T) and Branch (B). You do some work in B. You also add the file in T.
So when the merge occurs you merge B -> T. It checks the difference in B after 1st of June and it sees that in B there is no such file so it is marked deleted. 
If you merge T->B it will see that there is a new file in trunk and it will create it in the Branch

Comment: Thanks  Veselin Davidov . Sorry if i am frustating you. But does that means  branch changes  will override the trunk changes ? How will merge
tool know here whether its conflicting change or its need to override ?

Comment: say if i modify one existing line under file in trunk .Now incoming change from branch will show it as coflicting change or will override it?
Similarly if i add two lines or delete two line(instead of modifying existing line), how incoming change will behave here ?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow instruction if TSVN help for reintegrate via 'Merging Two Different Trees' than it can be easily explained. You ask apply difference between `trunk` - `branch` to working copy.

File exists in trunk but absent in branch, then difference - 'delete file'

This difference applied to working copy and silently (no conflicts here) delete file.

Also you can check that after merge your working copy should look exacly as branch. This is what reintegrate merge doing - make destination branch ('trunk' in your case) equal to source barnch.

If you still want perfrom reintegration merge via 'Merging Two Different Trees', then first perfrom sync merge trunk -> branch. In this case branch will contains both trunk and branch changes and reintegrate will look like copy branch changes into trunk (but again, actually it is made trunk equal to branch)

Comment: As you suggested in your comment that  fror back merging branch to trunk, we should use `Merge a range of revisions `.But in that case I need to manually mention revision number of branch which I need merge to trunk. If I leave it blank, it will merge all revision of branch to trunk. Then it will be kind of 'Merging Two Different Trees` if I leave revisions textbox blank. Right  ?

Comment: And if I need to manually mention revision numbers  when using `Merge a range  of revisions` ,is it not error prone. May be somebody miss some revision