# Tortoise Merging Trunk to Branch delete folder on branch

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, branch, trunk

Good morning in my timezone.
I am merging the trunk to a branch , and during the process it deletes a folder that just exist in the branch(this folder is versioned). Why is this happening ?
Thanks in advance 
Best regards

Comment: Obvious reason - because this folder was deleted in trunk. Need more information if this is not the case. How yoy merge? Command, responses. Can you reproduce it on test repository?

Comment: I used the tortoise context menu option -> Merge - Merge two different trees -> Merge options "Working Copy"
And this folder never existed in trunk

Comment: Do not use 'Merge two different trees' for merge http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110196/file-is-shown-as-deleted-while-merging-branch-to-trunk